# append a line after pattern match ONLY after first occurrence

Tags: awk, sed

I have multiple file which looks like following

```
module ( 
input a;
output b;
);

xx inst_xx (
.in     (xxin),
.ou     (xxou)
);

assign a = b;

endmodule
```

I want to append a line after ONLY after first occurrence of `);` pattern

```
`include "defines.vh"
```

so finally it should look like

```
module ( 
input a;
output b;
);
`include "defines.vh"

xx inst_xx (
    .in     (xxin),
    .ou     (xxou)
);

assign a = b;

endmodule
```

Anything using `sed` or `awk` would be useful.

Comment: What about the block that starts with `xx inst_xx`? Should that be in the output as well?

Comment: No, the mentioned block `xx inst_xx` needs to be ignored. just now corrected the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ print } !flag && /);/ { print "`include \"defines.vh\""; flag = 1 }' file
module (
input a;
output b;
);
`include "defines.vh"

xx inst_xx (
.in     (xxin),
.ou     (xxou)
);

assign a = b;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed $'/);/{a`include "defines.vh"\n;:a;n;ba}' file
```

or:

```
sed -e '/);/{a`include "defines.vh"' -e ':a;n;ba}' file
```

This matches the first `);` and appends the required string then reads and prints the remainder of the file looping on the `n` command.

Comment: Can you explain what it does ?

Comment: I would be great if you explain each letter. thank you